# Mail configuration in Bugzilla

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I've installed bugzilla in my local machine (Windows 7) and its working good. But when I try to create a new account it says:

```
Traceback:
at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 179.
    Bugzilla::Mailer::MessageToMTA(...) called at Bugzilla/Token.pm line 89
    Bugzilla::Token::issue_new_user_account_token(...) called at Bugzilla/User.pm line 2423
    Bugzilla::User::check_and_send_account_creation_confirmation(...) called at C:/bugzilla/createaccount.cgi line 39
```

I followed the documentation provided in bugzilla. But unable to resolve this issue. Can anyone help this?

Comment: Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 179 is a comment in my version. Which is yours? And it looks like the actual error message is missing from your quote.

Comment: I am using latest version of  Bugzilla 5.1.1.